# Массовая обработка исключений

Tags: python, исключения

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли способ для массовой обработки исключения?
у меня код содержит много переменных.
По каждой переменной проходится цикл и извлекает данные из них для определенного тикера.
К примеру для некоторых тикеров данные есть, а для некоторых нет.
Условно говоря имеем:

```
import tradingview_ta

# ... Тикеры
tickers = ['BTCUSDT','APEUSDT']

data = TA_Handler(symbol=tickers, exchange="BINANCE",screener="crypto", interval="1d")

# ... Переменная из которой извлекаем данные
ema100 = data.get_analysis().moving_averages["COMPUTE"]["EMA100"]
```

Допустим для тикера BTCUSDT данные есть и мы их получаем.
А для второго тикера APEUSDT данных именно по этом запросу нету и я получаю ошибку

```
File "c:\Users\Users\Desktop\python\test.py", line 24, in worker
print(moving["COMPUTE"]["EMA100"])
KeyError: 'EMA100'
```

Если я обработаю эту переменную вот таким образом, то все в порядке

```
ema100 = 0

try:
    ema100 = moving["COMPUTE"]["EMA100"]
except (KeyError):
    ema100 == 'Null'
```

Так как все данные я сохраняю в Excel, то в поле EMA100 для определенного тикера я получаю 'Null'

Можно ли как-то массово обработать все переменные, и в случае KeyError просто получить 'Null'
Или нужно каждую переменную обрабатывать способом, что я указал выше?
Я пробовал просто блок с переменными заключать в Try / Except, ну KeyError все равно получаю.

```
worksheet.write(f'A{count}', f'{ema100}, format1)
```

Или как тут вместо f'{ema100} указать что то наподобии :

```
worksheet.write(f'A{count}', f'{Была ошибка, поэтому тут будет 'null'}, format1)
```

Comment: `ema100 = moving["COMPUTE"].get("EMA100", "Null")`

Comment: спасибо. Получается это без Try / Except прописывается просто ?

Comment: Да. так и есть.